# Getting the Date of Some Day of Last Week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

In learning how to get the date of a day of the week from the previous week (e.g. the date of Monday from the previous week), I found the following two expressions coming up commonly, where you change the very last number (e.g. 0=Monday) depending on which day you want:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0)

SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Both seem to return the correct Date `2017-05-29` when I run it today (2017-06-17).

My question is - how does this work?  It seems to be getting a count of weeks since `6` or `7` weeks after `1900-01-01`? And why does it work with both a `6` and `7`?

Also, are there edge cases one would need to be aware of where it might not give the expected results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This takes advantage of the fact that `1900-01-01` is a Monday. So adding `n` number of weeks will also be a Monday.

Here are the `datetime` values that are being represented by the integers in that expression:

```
dateadd(week, datediff(week, 7 /*'19000108'*/, getdate()), 0 /*'19000101'*/)
```

Adding the number of weeks since `1900-01-08` (the week after the first Monday) to `1900-01-01` returns one week less than the current week, i.e. Monday of last week.

These three are equivalent:

```
select dateadd(week, datediff(week, 7 , getdate()), 0)
select dateadd(week, datediff(week, '19000108', getdate()), '19000101')
select dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate())-1, 0)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BQX59903

Comment: This all makes sense except 1 thing... the 6 and the 7 - why would one add either 6 or 7 weeks from the first monday?  I suspect they used 6/7 thinking aout "days", but it's not days, its `wk` right?

Comment: @GWR `6` or `7` are `1900-01-07` and `1900-01-08` respectively, not weeks. The likely cause of someone using `7` would be if their native calendar week starts on a Monday, vs US where it starts on Sunday. The reason `6` works even if someone has `set datefirst 1` (to set the first day of the week as Monday instead of Sunday) explicitly or implicitly by language setting, `datediff(week...)` is going to be performed as if `set datefirst 7` was in place. rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YWJRZ24690

Comment: I get it... I was mixing it up... the 6 and 7 I was thinking of as count of days or weeks, but its a value that resolves into a date expression... Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @GWR Happy to help!